# how do I set a delegate in a view that is not my main view

Tags: objective-c, uikit, delegates, uitextfield, uilabel

I have a xib. the xib has a button that swaps another xib.

the second xib has a uitextfield and a uilabel.

how do I make the keyboard go away when I'm done typing? what do I need to wire or code? the second xib has it's own class (called CustomSign.m)

Inside CustomSign.m, I've implemented the following method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
[customText resignFirstResponder];
signedLabel.text = customText.text;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
//assume textField is an ivar that is connected to the textfield in IB
[customText setDelegate:self];
}
```

I get the following warning

Class "CustomSign" does not implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol

Comment: @interface CustomSign: UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

I did that and it's not working still. when I click done, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove warning you need to specify in your `CustomSign` class declaration that it conforms to UITextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
@interface CustomSign: UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
...
```